# Outputting column means for arbitrary number of columns

Tags: r

I have attached [a screen shot of my data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqvhN.jpg). Each column represents daily data collected by a probe at half hour intervals. I want to output in a CSV file the daily averages for each probe. So far I have the following code

```
sink('d2.csv')
x<-1
y<-48
for(i in 1:123) {
    W=E.2.[x:y]
    M=mean(W)
    print(M)
    x<-x+48
    y<-y+48
}
sink()
```

which averages each column separately and writes it to a CSV file. What I
want to do is to have a code that could work on all the columns and write it to a CSV file.

```
    TIMESTAMP       E.2.    E.3.    E.4.    E.5.    E.6.    E.7.    E.8.    E.9.    E.10.   E.11.   E.12.   E.13.
1   3/16/2013 0:00  108.1   166.4   238.41  261.2   373.5   324.27  278.94  514.2   629.8   607.9   334.9   323.59
2   3/16/2013 0:30  109.5   165.6   237.4   261.19  367.1   324.2   278.53  513.2   631.8   609.3   335.0   323.19
3   3/16/2013 1:00  110.6   165.5   236.48  261.17  368.1   324.2   278.13  512.4   631.2   609.3   335.0   323.56
4   3/16/2013 1:30  111.4   165.6   235.69  261.13  375.1   324.2   277.49  511.6   629.1   606.6   335.2   323.5
5   3/16/2013 2:00  112.2   165.7   234.88  261.09  379.6   324.21  276.85  510.6   629.5   607.3   335.3   323.67
6   3/16/2013 2:30  112.3   166.2   234.3   261.09  378.2   324.21  276.38  509.9   630.7   607.6   335.6   323.88
```

Comment: If you want further help,  make a reproducible example. For example, paste the result of  `dput(df)` or perhaps `dput(head(df))` if the former is too big.

Comment: TIMESTAMP E.2. E.3. E.4. E.5. E.6. E.7. E.8. E.9. E.10. E.11. E.12. E.13.
1 3/16/2013 0:00 108.1 166.4 238.41 261.2 373.5 324.27 278.94 514.2 629.8 607.9 334.9 323.59
2 3/16/2013 0:30 109.5 165.6 237.4 261.19 367.1 324.2 278.53 513.2 631.8 609.3 335 323.19
3 3/16/2013 1:00 110.6 165.5 236.48 261.17 368.1 324.2 278.13 512.4 631.2 609.3 335 323.56
4 3/16/2013 1:30 111.4 165.6 235.69 261.13 375.1 324.2 277.49 511.6 629.1 606.6 335.2 323.5
5 3/16/2013 2:00 112.2 165.7 234.88 261.09 379.6 324.21 276.85 510.6 629.5 607.3 335.3 323.67

Comment: Thank you John for a prompt response. I attached the data you requested, hope its not too messy!

Comment: That helps, but ideally it should be edited into the question itself, and have the property that the reader can copy-paste it into R directly. What you have would still require something like `read.table()` the nice thing about `dput` is that it gives a copy-pasteable which can directly work.

Comment: Installed zoo, but your suggestion it not work. I have pasted the data in the initial question to see if that helps you to make suggestions

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know for sure without knowing more about the structure of your data and exactly what you are trying to do, but by using the [rollapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-1/topics/rollapply) function, everything that you need can probably be put in two lines of code (assuming that `df` is the name of your dataframe):

```
library(zoo)
write.csv(rollapply(df[,-1],48,mean,by = 4),"d2.csv")
```

**On Edit**: I used `by = 4` because your code had lines like `x <- x + 4`. You seem to want to increment by 48. It isn't really a sliding mean any more in the sense that successive windows are now disjoint, though this approach still works:

```
write.csv(rollapply(df[,-1],48,mean,by = 48),"d2.csv")
```

will give you 123 rows per column.

Comment: I tried installing zoo with following, it did not work

Comment: > install.packages("zoo_1.6-4.tar.gz", repos = NULL ); 
Warning: invalid package 'zoo_1.6-4.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/Users/clahiri/DOCUME~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\clahiri\Documents\R\R-3.4.2\library" "zoo_1.6-4.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘zoo_1.6-4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: `zoo` is a standard CRAN package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html Perhaps you were trying to install an older version of the package. RStudio is useful for painlessly installing packages. I changed the documentation link to point to the current version.

Comment: I installed the package, however was not able to make the script work! The original questions does have a screen shot of the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to make the script work"? I am able to get it to work (using sliding windows of width 3 with strides of `by = 2`) on the data you gave and it works for me. If it doesn't work for you, say how. Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? No errors but not the result that you were looking for?

Comment: The file that is outputs NA's in each row and column, and the waning says "1: In mean.default(data[posns], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA". In the rollapply function I understand the logic of all the arguments except the "by=4". What is that for?

Comment: "argument is not numeric" is a red flag. Are you sure that your columns (other than the first, which is excluded by the `df[,-1]`) are numeric as opposed to character? You might have to fix the types. Since you still haven't given a reproducible example using `dput()` it is hard to be sure. The `by = 4` corresponds to the `+4` in your code. You started with a window of width 48 and in each pass through the loop you slide the window by 4 units.

Comment: I fixed the NA and the code now works, but it should be outputting 123 values per columns (ie from March 16 to July 17), but the otput has many more rows. Can I send you the CSV file?

Comment: the dput(head(df) output is is too large to paste here too!

Comment: If you want to send me a csv file, I'll look at it (but maybe not tonight). My e-mail can be obtained from my profile.